# MongoDB Java driver: distinct and iterative

Tags: java, mongodb, iteration, distinct

because `DBCollection#distinct()` returns type List and not type DBCursor like `DBCollection#find()`.
Unfortunately, My distinct's result is too big. So I need a good way too loop over distinct values of a query.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can get similar behavior using the aggregation framework,which supports cursors.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#retrieve-distinct-values for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Driver doesn't provide the facility to get the distinct objects like by cursor, We can do in this way, I don't know which is a right solution as a performance point of view.

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("your_collection");
    List<String> lst=coll.distinct("your_property");
    for(String l:lst){
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("your_property", l);
        DBObject object=coll.findOne(query);
        System.out.println(object);
    }
```

Comment: My problem is List<String> lst will be over a billion elements. Therefor, I cannot use distinction function. Jyemin suggests using aggregation. And it works. Anyway, thanks for your help. :)